# Use Django URL pattern matcher as component

Tags: django, python-3.x

I guess it's possible, but i still didn't find any solution. I'm looking for a way to use Django URL pattern matcher for another data processing

For example: 

I have following pattern 

`"MySpecific-(?P<my_parameter>)-(?P<my_second_parameter>)"`

 
and following regular string

`"MySpecific-test-123"`

so what i want is to extract parameters by pattern form regular string in a dict shape

```
{
  "my_parameter": "test",
  "my_second_parameter: "123"
}
```

Pseudo code:

```
import matcher from django_matcher_package

my_pattern = "MySpecific-(?P<my_parameter>)-(?P<my_second_parameter>)"
my_string = "MySpecific-test-123"

extracted_values = matcher.match(my_pattern, my_string)
```

Comment: Django simply uses regex...

Comment: Yes i know, but there is something else. This pattern seems to be regex non friendly ```test/url/<int:count>``` but it works fine

Comment: @dorintufar: yes that's the new way of doing them, that is completely distinct from the regex-based ones.

Answer (score 1):

That's just Python's regular expression support:

```
>>> pattern="MySpecific-(?P<my_parameter>.+)-(?P<my_second_parameter>.+)"
>>> s="MySpecific-test-123"
>>> import re
>>> match = re.match(pattern, s)
>>> match.groupdict()
{'my_parameter': 'test', 'my_second_parameter': '123'}
```

Note I added '.+' to your pattern twice, otherwise there wouldn't be anything to match in those groups.

Comment: This way will work 100%, but it will take too long to explain to system operators that after each parameter there should be additional ```.+``` characters xD

Comment: @dorintufar: they aren't extra, you also need them in your Django URLs. The one you had wouldn't match on your string in Django either.

Comment: Yep, i see. Thank you